# Set of subsets containing individual elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the set $S=\{a,b,c\}$. I am trying to formalize a general approach to fragmenting the set $S$, s.t. a fragmentation function $F$ is a function that maps from $S$ to $2^S$.

The granularity, of course depends on the specific function, e.g. the function $F_C(S)=\{\forall t|t\in S\}$ is very coarse-granular that returns the set {{a,b,c}}.

However, how do I formalize a fragmentation function that returns the set {{a},{b},{c}}? The only idea I have for it is $F_F=\{\forall\{t\}|t\in S\}$, however it just seems wrong. Is the function $F_C$ even correctly formulated?

Edit: My question is generally this: How do I formalize a function $F_F(S)$ that is injective and maps $a$ to $\{a\}$, $b$ to $\{b\}$ etc?

Thanks! - Christian

Comment: What's a fragmentation function?  Specifically, what properties do you want your function $F$ to have?

Comment: @lulu - Essentially a function that creates a set of fragments, where a fragment $f$ is a subset of $S$, $f\subseteq S$, that is $F: S\rightarrow 2^S$.

Comment: Not sure that clarifies anything.  A function from $S$ to $2^S$ can only have at most three values in its range.  I guess you can pick whatever three subsets you like.  Are you sure you don't want the domain of $F$ to be the power set of $S$?

Comment: @lulu I thought the power set $S$ was $2^S$? But anyways, yes that is what I want

Comment: So, you want a function from the power set of $S$ to $2^S$?   What properties would you like that function to have?

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are looking for here.  If you just want a bijection from the power set of $S$ to the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, then map a subset to the binary number that has a $1$ if the relevant entry is in the subset and $0$ otherwise.  Thus $\{a\}\mapsto 100_2\quad \{b\}\mapsto 010_2\quad \{a,c\}\mapsto 101_2$ and so on.  Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It is supposed to be a function that maps elements in $S$ to elements in the power set of S. For example, $F_C$ maps all elements in $S$ to the same element in the power set, specifically $\{a,b,c\}$, and $F_F$ is a bijective function that maps $a$ to $\{a\}$, $b$ to $\{b\}$ etc. I am just not sure of how to formalize this :)

Comment: Well, I don't understand.  I don't think I am helping.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $F:S\to\wp(S)$ is prescribed by $x\mapsto\{x\}$ then the graph of $F$ can be recognized as the set (of ordered pairs):$$\{\langle x,\{x\}\rangle\mid x\in S\}$$

However this function is only bijective if $S$ is empty or is a singleton.

It is injective though, and to make it bijective its codomain must be restricted to its image which is the set $\{\{x\}\mid x\in S\}$.

Then we are dealing with $F:S\to\{\{x\}\mid x\in S\}$ prescribed by $x\mapsto\{x\}$.

This function has the same graph as the original one, but if concepts like "bijective" are at stake then functions cannot be identified with their graphs only.

---

I am not sure about my own understanding of the question. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you. I meant that the function $F$ is injective, not bijective (sorry about that). Is $\{\langle x,\{x\}\rangle | x\in S\}$ then the correct formalization of $F$ given that any $x$ is mapped to $\{x\}$?

Comment: In set theory a function $f$ is a set of ordered pairs that has a special property: if $\langle x,y\rangle,\langle x,z\rangle\in f$ then $y=z$. That is the case for $F=\{\langle x,\{x\}\rangle\mid x\in S\}$. So it is a function and it is prescribed by $x\mapsto\{x\}$. I don't know what you mean exactly with "formalization".

Comment: I see, I think I just misunderstood the notation of defining functions :). Another question - is the function $F_C=\{\langle x,\{S\}\rangle\}$ then correct notation for a function where all elements in $S$ maps to $\{S\}$?

Comment: No, it should be $\{\langle x,\{S\}\rangle\mid x\in S\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you ask: My question is generally this: How do I formalize a function $F_F(S)$ that is injective and maps $a$ to $\{a\}$, $b$ to $\{b\}$ etc?

Let: $$S=\{a,b,c\}$$

(Aside: the above explication of $S$ is useless, since the following set and function will hold for any set.)

And, $$A=\{\{x\}| x\in S\}$$ then,

$$F_F:A\rightarrow S$$
$$F_F=\{(x,\{x\})|x\in S \land \{x\}\in A;x=x\}$$

Or to avoid ambiguity,

$$A=\{\{y\}| y\in S\}$$

$$F_F=\{(x,\{y\})|x\in S \land \{y\}\in A;x=y\}$$

Notice:
$$x_1\rightarrow y_1$$
$$x_2\rightarrow y_2$$
$$x_n\rightarrow y_n$$

Therefore,

$$(\forall x\in S (\exists y\in A) \ni f(x)=\{y\})$$
$$(f(x_1)=\{y_1\} \land f(x_2)=\{y_1\})\implies x_1=x_2$$

Meaning the function is bijective.